# How to know a value for field already exists and it was deleted?

Tags: python, django

How can we know that a value in field already exists however it does not exists in the table right now?(because we delete the field)

e.g. We have a table that has field with name "title".

we had value "x" in this "title" field and right now it does not exists and we deleted the value "x" value.

So my question is, how can we know that?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, you have a field that can be nullable but you want to know if that field has ever had a value or not. The only way of practically managing this would be to either:

a) Have another field on the same model that tracks whether the field has ever had a value

`title_had_value = models.BooleanField(...`

But this doesn't tell you much unless you have a bunch of fields.

b) Have another model that tracks the history of the field, something like this with whatever data you need to track and manage

```py
model TitleHistory(models.Model):
   title_value = models.CharField(...
   set_on = models.DateTimeField(...
   is_current = models.BooleanField
```